# In wordpress, Not able to insert Custom registration form data into Database and my PHP code is printing on the Form(which i have kept in shortcode)

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Custom Form to Collect the data from Customer. So i used below PHP code to insert the data into DB.

`

```
<?php
require_once(‘../../../wp-load.php’);
global $wpdb;
$first_name = $_POST[‘first_name’];
$last_name = $_POST[‘last_name’];
$user_email = $_POST[‘user_email’];
$table_name = $wpdb ->prefix . “Customer”;
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(‘cust_id’=>2, ‘first_name’ =>$first_name, ‘last_name’ =>$last_name ,user_email=>$user_email) ); ?>
```

`

This Code i have taken from google and I dont see any error on php code. But it is printing from prefix.”Customer” ….. to till the end of the code in Registration form while loading. After a very long trial i identified that the “>” symbol on the code is not taking and it is printing. So i changed all “>” symbol to “>” then i dont see any line printing on my Registration Form.

But Once i Click Register button it is not inserting data into my Custom Table(“Customer” table) rather it is not showing any error too..

So I guess my short code is not taking php code, Please let me know what if anyone came across this kind of issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is `cust_id` hardcoded as `2`? If `cust_id` #2 already exists, it is not able to insert another if it is unique.

Comment: Not sure if the upside down / rightside up quotation marks will affect your output or not. Never actually did that before. Try making them all the same (rightside up)

Comment: Actually i just tried by hardcoding the value to check whether it is working for this or not(to make the code very simple). However even if i use select query it is not working there.. I have given this PHP code on the shortcode in a page where my form reference i have given.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WP however I believe I can decipher what is going on and what is needed.

Try this. It will pull the highest `cust_id` and add one to it, and assign it as a variable to the insert query.

```
<?php
require_once(‘../../../wp-load.php’);
global $wpdb;    
$first_name = $_POST[‘first_name’];
$last_name = $_POST[‘last_name’];
$user_email = $_POST[‘user_email’];
$table_name = $wpdb ->prefix . “Customer”;
$custID = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT cust_id FROM $table_name ORDER BY cust_id DESC limit 1 ");
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(‘cust_id’=>($custID + 1), ‘first_name’ =>$first_name, ‘last_name’ =>$last_name ,user_email=>$user_email) ); ?>
```

Comment: It is not working for me even for simple select query. I have given this PHP code on the shortcode in a page where my form reference i have given. the code is printing on form once loaded from prefix.'Customer.. to till the end. If i change the greater than symbols to html equivalent then it is not printing on  form but still it is not inserting the data